# Homestead ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED After Mac OS Update

Tags: laravel, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I recently updated to Big Sur on my Mac and haven't been able to access any of my VMs as web pages since. I've destroyed and rebuilt this VM using Homestead's expected installation process.

- VirtualBox 6.1.28
- Latest Homestead version from release branch
- Vagrant 2.2.18

[This is the error I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeUC8.png)

After long hours spent researching this loads of people seem to resolve it by adding the site to their hosts file. To confirm I have added this to hosts:

[Error when viewing the URL without site in hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCWi.png)

**Update**: I'm able to view the VM if I go to http://localhost:8000/. Going to http://192.168.10.10 doesn't work.
From the vagrant box using `curl 192.168.10.10` produces the expected HTML output of that page. So does `curl localhost:8000` from my machine. If I try `curl 192.168.10.10` from my machine I get `curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument`.

I've tried every other network configuration within Virtualbox and using NAT is the only one that allows the SSH connection. It seems requests aren't making it to the VirtualBox.. probably because there's an error stating the socket isn't connected.

[Socket stats seems to show it's listening on port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1khT.png)

As of now I have destroyed and rebuilt the box again, so it is as close to an expected installation that anyone should have.

p.s. "site.test" is a placeholder for the actual name.

Here is my Homestead.yaml: https://pastebin.com/qhPdWCNv

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/code/

sites:
    - map: site.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site/public
      php: "7.4"

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

#ports:
#    - send: 33060 # MySQL/MariaDB
#      to: 3306
#    - send: 4040
#      to: 4040
#    - send: 54320 # PostgreSQL
#      to: 5432
#    - send: 8025 # Mailhog
#      to: 8025
#    - send: 9600
#      to: 9600
#    - send: 27017
#      to: 27017
```

Here is my hosts file: https://pastebin.com/Y6Re15iy

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
192.168.10.10   site.test
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters this issue I fixed this by updating the VM to a new IP, changing the domain, and clearing the dns cache (dscacheutil –flushcache).

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant 6.1.28 seems to restrict the valid IP address of a guest.
Took me hours to figure this out, read then manual.
Solved by changing my Homestead.yaml ip to 192.168.56.0 and also altered the ip in /etc/hosts

From the manual:
On Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris Oracle VM VirtualBox will only allow IP addresses in 192.68.56.0/21 range to be assigned to host-only adapters.

Comment: I've updated to use that IP instead and I get the exact same socket error on that IP instead